# Selenium Grid in Python - functional tests timeout after first test everytime

Tags: python, django, selenium, docker, selenium-grid

So I have been trying to write functional tests for my django application, and I appear to be having some strange behaviour: every single time I run my tests, Selenium hangs indefinitely after the first test, only when I reboot the hub and node containers does it let me run another test, after which it hangs forever again. I have studied [this thread](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/87) as at first glance it appears to be the same error, but even with those changes I have the same problem.

Description of my setup:
I am using docker-compose, with 3 (main) services: django, selenium_hub, and selenium_firefox. Find my docker-compose.yml below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: 
        context: django
        dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./django/my_web:/src/my_web/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks: ["my-net"]

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes: 
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/static:/usr/share/nginx/djangodocker/static
      - ./nginx/certs/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/certs:ro
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on: 
      - web
    networks: ["my-net"]

  selenium_hub:
    container_name: selenium_hub
    image: selenium/hub
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    environment:
      - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null
    shm_size: 512MB
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    networks: ["my-net"]

  selenium_firefox:
    container_name: selenium_firefox
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    shm_size: 512MB
    environment:
      - DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium_hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
    ports:
      - "5901:5900"
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub  
    networks: ["my-net"]

networks:
  my-net:
```

As you can see I've tried mounting /dev/shm, setting shm_size and setting the environment variable: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null to no avail.

I think the cause of my problem may lie in my test itself so I have included the code below:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class SeleniumTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('Setting up...')
        self.firefox = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://selenium_hub:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
        )
        print('Done; connected') 

    def test_visit_site_with_firefox(self): 
        selenium = self.firefox
        selenium.get('http://web:8000')
        assert "Home" in selenium.title
        self.firefox.quit()

     .... more tests below...
```

Yet whenever I run `manage.py test --verbosity=2` I get the result of the first test, then it hangs after the `print("Setting up...")` line, and I've waited up to 40 minutes without any error message.

I was wondering if someone has noticed or experience similar behaviour in Selenium, using the `:latest` tag for all images, on docker version 18.06.1-ce and docker-compose version 1.22.0.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this myself. It was really simple I just needed a `tearDown()` function in my `TestCase` class which exited Selenium to allow it to continue to the next test case.

Hopefully this helps someone!